# If $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\nabla u\nabla v+V(x)uv\,dx=0$ for all $v\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$, can we conclude that $u=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $V(x)\geq 1$ be defined in $\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfying that $V$ is increasing, radial and coercive. It is well know that
$$
\lambda_1(V)=\inf_{u\in E, u\neq 0}\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|\nabla u|^2+V(x)u^2\,dx}{\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}u^2\,dx}\geq 1,
$$
where $E=\{u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^2): \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}V(x)u^2\,dx<\infty\}$ is a Banach space endowed with the norm $\|u\|^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|\nabla u|^2+V(x)u^2\,dx$.

Now suppose that $u\in W_{loc}^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ for any $1<p<2$. Here is my question. If
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\nabla u\nabla v+V(x)uv\,dx=0,\quad \text{for all } v\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2),
$$
can we conclude that $u=0$? If $u\in E$, this is obviously. But when $u\notin E$, does this proposition still hold?

Any help will be appreciated a lot!!!!

Comment: Actually, if $u\in H^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, this is also right. But how to deal with the case that 1<p<2?